# How do add a header on extjs 3.0 groupTab example?

Tags: extjs

i am trying to  add a header on extjs 3.0 groupTab example ,and it has given me a headache for some days now.AnyBody with an idea how i can approach that?

Answer (score 0):

In groupTab example the component header is modified so that it appears at left side of component(it also can appear at right side). If you want your component to have one more header at the top, you always can set it as an item of another container which has normal header.

Comment: @Steve, I guess grouptabs.js. Try replace Viewport items to this `[xtype: 'panel', header: true, items:[ /* original tabpanel config */ ]]`

Comment: ,i have tried that but it doesn't work   here  is my grouptab.js

Comment: @Steve. Maybe you should use `title` instead of `header`. Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/SJp38/3/)

Comment: yaeh thats sorts the issue of the header,is there a way i can add a panel on top so that i can dispay the company logo the user who is logged in

Comment: solution::var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:'border',
        title:'Nairobi Javasoft',
        header:true,
        items:[{
         xtype: 'panel',
            title: '',
            height: 100,
            region:'north',
         items: new Crmheader() 
        }, {----groubtabpanel----}